# JsValue filter out null values

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

I am trying to figure out how to avoid `null` values. My problem is, that I am querying an API and it returns a `null` value.

Here's an example:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class InnerExample(value: String)

object InnerExample {
def fromJson(json: JsValue) = InnerExample(
    value = (json \ "value")as[String]
}

case class Example(innerValue: Option[InnerExample])

object Example {
def fromJson(json: JsValue) = Example(
    optionalValue = (json \ "innerValue").asOpt[String].map(InnerExample.apply)
    )
}
```

The problem I am having is that `asOpt` transforms `innerValue` not to a `None`, but to a `Some(null)`. I understand why and it makes a lot of sense. But I need to figure out a way to deal with it. Something more elegant than matching for `Some(null)`. I am very grateful for any ideas.

Comment: Could you do `Option(json \ "innerValue").map(InnerExample)` instead?

Comment: Sadly I can't. I have to pass it on as json because those case classes go a few level deep and have for more parameters than shown here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider [`readNullable`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsPath@readNullable[T](implicitr:play.api.libs.json.Reads[T]):play.api.libs.json.Reads[Option[T]]). Here is working example:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class InnerExample(value: String)
case class Example(innerValue: Option[InnerExample])

object InnerExample {
  implicit val format = Json.format[InnerExample]
}

object Example {
  implicit val jsonread: Reads[Example] =
    (JsPath \ "innerValue").readNullable[InnerExample].map(Example.apply)
}

object NullableJson extends App {
  val jsonSomeStr = """{ "innerValue": { "value": "woohoo" } }"""
  val jsonSome = Json.parse(jsonSomeStr).as[Example] 
  println(jsonSome) // Example(Some(InnerExample(woohoo)))

  val jsonNullStr = """{ "innerValue": null }"""
  val jsonNull = Json.parse(jsonNullStr).as[Example]
  println(jsonNull) // Example(None)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And please forgive me for taking two days to answer you after asking you for help. There were unexpected circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answer from @Mario Galic, I went back to my code and opened up the documentation of JSLookups, which is what I get back when I use method `\` of a `JsValue`. Turns out it does have a way to deal with `null`-values. It is done like this:

```
optionalValue = (json \ "innerValue").validateOpt[String].get.map(InnerExample.apply)
```

I think Mario's way is cleaner and should be recommended, but in my case it would means rewrite 10 case classes and my way is faster in modifying my existing code. Still, that is the reason why I will mark Mario's answer as accepted answer.